# What is wrong with this promisify?

Tags: node.js, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

As an exercise I am trying to convert https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/nodejs from a callback style to a promises style and then refactor it into an async/await using `util.promisify`.

Everything went fine until the final function.  The original is:

```
function listMajors(auth) {
  const sheets = google.sheets({version: 'v4', auth});
  sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
    spreadsheetId: '1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms',
    range: 'Class Data!A2:E',
  }, (err, res) => {
    if (err) return console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
    const rows = res.data.values;
    if (rows.length) {
      console.log('Name, Major:');
      // Print columns A and E, which correspond to indices 0 and 4.
      rows.map((row) => {
        console.log(`${row[0]}, ${row[4]}`);
      });
    } else {
      console.log('No data found.');
    }
  });
}
```

The promisified version is:

```
function listMajors(auth) {
  const sheets = google.sheets({version: 'v4', auth});

  const getValues = util.promisify(sheets.spreadsheets.values.get);
  getValues({
      spreadsheetId: '1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms',
      range: 'Class Data!A2:E',
    }).then(function (res) {
      const rows = res.data.values;
      if (rows.length) {
        // Print columns A and E, which correspond to indices 0 and 4.
        rows.map((row) => {
          console.log(`${row[0]}, ${row[1]}`);
        });
      }
    }).catch(err => console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err));
}
```

The original returns the spreadsheet.  The promisified version says, `The API returned an error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'context' of undefined`.  I can't figure out why they are different.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your promisified version is probably losing the parent object of the method you're trying to call.

If you change it to this, that issue should be fixed:

```
let values = sheets.spreadsheets.values;
values.getP = util.promisify(sheets.spreadsheets.values.get);
values.getP().then(...);
```

What's important here is that when calling your promisified version, you're still using the `values` object reference as in `values.getP()` so that the promisified function still gets the proper `this` value.

---

FYI, you could probably also bind the proper object to the method:

```
const getValues = util.promisify(sheets.spreadsheets.values.get).bind(sheets.spreadsheets.values);
```

---

Here's a simple example to demonstrate:

```js
class Test {
    constructor() {
        this.data = "Hello";
    }

    demo() {
        console.log(this);
    }
}
 
 
let t = new Test();

// this works just fine
t.demo();

// this doesn't work because x has lost the t object
// so when you call x(), it no longer has a reference to the object instance
// It needs to be called like obj.method()
let x = t.demo;
x();
```

---

This comes up so often, it would be nice to have this snippet of code handy:

```
const util = require('util');
if (!util.promisifyMethod) {
    util.promisifyMethod = function(fn, obj) {
         return util.promisify(fn).bind(obj);
    }
}
```

Then, anytime you want to promisify a method of some object, you could use it:

```
const getValues = util.promisifyMethod(sheets.spreadsheets.values.get, sheets.spreadsheets.values);
```